# Python Pandas - Groupby and make column values headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is a list of organisations (multiple rows per organisation) which has a `boolean` value associated with it.

So organisation A has 3 `true` rows and 3 `false` i.e.

```
Organisation  Value
A             True
A             True
A             False
A             False
A             True
A             False
B             True
B             True
C             False
C             False
```

I want to get it into the format where I have each organisation listed only once, and the `true` and `false` values under the value column as new column headers like this (and then counted):

```
Organisation  True   False
A              3       3
B              2       0
C              0       2
```

Currently by code is like this:

```
sqlDf.groupby(['Organisation','Value']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

But that doesnt do what I need it to do.

Any advice?

Comment: Perfect, thank you once again jezreal. Works just the way I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.crosstab` -

```
pd.crosstab(df.Organisation, df.Value)

Value         False  True 
Organisation              
A                 3      3
B                 0      2
C                 2      0
```

---

**Option 2**
Tensor dot products with `get_dummies` -

```
df.Organisation.str.get_dummies().T.dot(pd.get_dummies(df.Value))

   False  True 
A      3      3
B      0      2
C      2      0
```

Credit to @piRSquared, picked this neat trick up from him a while back, and have used it in a few answers to date.

---

**Option 3**
`get_dummies` + `sum` along the index -

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Organisation').Value).sum(level=0)

              False  True 
Organisation              
A                 3      3
B                 0      2
C                 2      0
```

---

**Option 4**
Similar to jezrael's, but uses `value_counts` and only groups on one column, so it should be performant.

```
df.groupby('Organisation').Value.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

Value         False  True 
Organisation              
A                 3      3
B                 0      2
C                 2      0
```

---

**Option 5**
`pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index='Organisation', columns='Value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

Value         False  True 
Organisation              
A                 3      3
B                 0      2
C                 2      0
```

In this case, `pivot_table` lets you specify only two params, the `index` and `columns`, since you're aggregating on the number of values per cell.

Comment: Thank you Coldspeed! Your answer works perfectly too! Now I am stuck having to choose between yours and jezraels answer as the accepted one as they both work perfectly. I guess yours is shorter!

Comment: @ScoutEU Added option 4, just fyi ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, so what solution is the fastest?

Comment: @jezrael Ok. I have 5 options. Which is similar? Third? Last?

Comment: @jezrael Hmm, okay, I'll sign it then. Since we both ended up answering this one, let's excuse each other :)

Comment: Yes, I answer because a bit difference with `sort=False` in groupby, but now see it is not important there ;) So it happens ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`, also if importan ordering of values add `sort=False` to `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Organisation','Value'], sort=False).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Value         True   False
Organisation              
A                 3      3
B                 2      0
C                 0      2
```

---

```
df = (
      df.groupby(['Organisation','Value'], sort=False)
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
      )
print (df)
  Organisation  True  False
0            A     3      3
1            B     2      0
2            C     0      2
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as it lets me. Thank you again